# Assertion to compare Current time in Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

I am new to selenium and java.. I need to do a check, in which my app creates a move for a person from current time(as start time) to a custom time... And in my test scenario, I need to check whether the start time is equal to the current time at which that move was created. Below I have the piece of code in which I have manually given the current time in Assert.. But I can't change it each time during the test run.. Can anyone help me to get the current time in hh:mm am/pm format and compare with the start time and give pass or fail in my test output?

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement element1 = wait.until(
                            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                              By.xpath("//*[@id='tabpanel-t0-2']/tpr-summary-page/ion-content/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ion-card/ion-row[1]/ion-col/ion-row[2]")
                            )
                          );
String element = driver.findElement(
                          By.xpath("//*[@id='tabpanel-t0-2']/tpr-summary-page/ion-content/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ion-card/ion-row[1]/ion-col/ion-row[2]/div[1]/label[1]")
                       )
                       .getText();
Assert.assertTrue(element.contains("1:35"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current time in the `HH:mm` format by using the `java.util.Date()` library.
In your case, you can assert the value like:

```
Assert.assertTrue(element.contains(new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm").format(new java.util.Date())));
```

This will always assert the value with the current timestamp.

Comment: I tried this, but my test case failed even when that element had the current time:FAILED: rightNowToClockout
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]

Comment: FAILED: rightNowToClockout
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]

Comment: The expected value from which you are checking, is it in 24hr format or is it in 12hr format ?

Comment: Its 12 hour format... any changes to the above piece of code if its 12 hour format?

Comment: Yes i have made a little change in the answer, please pick the new answer.